# Brush to "Spawn" Several meshes on surface?

Tags: mesh

I have a ground and i would like to put lots of grass meshes [ 2 planes , With a grass texture , Image below ] I want to know if its possible to add lots of these meshes on the surface to where i click , instead of having to duplicate then place each one.[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use particles

Comment: how do i use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both of the planes that make the grass into a single object.

[image]

On the ground plane create a particle system. On the render section select **object** and assign the grass as **Dupli Object**.

Make sure the emitter start and end is 1 and the lifetime is as long as the animation you want to make.
Disable gravity. Make the particle size 1 and give it some randomness.

If your grass comes out flat to the ground just enable the rotation box.

[image]

[image]

sample file here: [image]