# Duplicate object in different sizes

Tags: modeling

My goal is to make a field of grass in blender. I have one "blade of grass".

I want to duplicate it 100 times, and make each element a different size.

How can I do this?

Greeting Pat

for a better view i upload screenshot for blender.

[image]

Comment: To make grass use particles see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/brush-to-spawn-several-meshes-on-surface http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5577/how-do-you-create-grass

Comment: If you would like to thank the helper do so in a comment like this.  Answer entries are for educational answers.

Comment: my apologies, First steps are always difficult :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

### 1) Hair Particle system

Just set random size to 1 as in the picture below

[image]

### 2) 2D Arrays & Randomize transform

Duplicate the object 10x10 times

[image]

Than apply modifers, enter edit mode, spilt by loose parts.

Now you'll have 100 different objects. Run the command Randomize Transform and set the XYZ Pos, Rot, Scale variance factors and the seed.

[image]

Obiuvsly the first method gives you the opportunity to change the base object at anytime, so it usually preferred.

### 3) Random Object Array add-on

It's an add you can find on [Blender Market](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/blender/all-products/random-object-array/) (so it's not free). As stated by the author:

> A particle system is great for hair, particles, fur, even grass. But it can become an obstacle for other purposes. Compared to a particle system, the Random Object Array add-on offers much more control over random values like rotation, position, **scale**.

Here's a video about it:

https://youtu.be/ugaEllRttAk?t=8m13s

Comment: Thanks! I even did not expect such a help like This:) i think i will stay here a little longer:p

Comment: yeap, its work :) big thanks to You. But unfortunately file dont want open in unreal engine;/  http://i.imgur.com/9I9jfkd.jpg?1