# Multiplying an object on a plain

Tags: game-engine, objects

I've made a piece of grass.
I'd like to now multiply it over my whole plain (which is a hill) for my game. 
Copy and pasting an individual piece of grass would take me forever, I'm hoping there is a better solution for this.
Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brush to "Spawn" Several meshes on surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/brush-to-spawn-several-meshes-on-surface)

Comment: Blender game engine, that can only be done in Cycles render or Blender render :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution for this is to use a particle system.

1. Select your mountain
2. Go into the particle system tab in the properties
3. Set Physics to No, Render to "Object" and set your grass object as "Dupli Object" (if you got more than one grass object create a group and use this group instead)
4. Hit play for tiny second all your grass particles should now appear.
5. Toy around with other setting or have a look into the blender documentation
6. Go to the modifer tab and hit convert on the particle system to make all the particles into real objects

Comment: Does this work in Blender Game mode?

Comment: you will have to make the changes in "blender render" mode but if you convert the particle system as described in step 6. it will definitely work.

Comment: Wait are you saying that blender render can be used for the game engine, because someone told me cycles render and blender render can't be used??

Comment: No, he said you model in Blender and convert the objects into BGE-conform objects. And no, cycles and and the Blender renderer do not apply to the BGE.