# adding grass to a scene

Tags: materials, particles

[image: my scene]

Is there a way to add grass all over my plane without placing the grass manually?[image: grass]

Comment: Yes. However, the answer is too detailed for a simple version here, so try [this tutorial](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-grassy-meadow-scene).

Comment: possible dupliate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89334/multiplying-an-object-on-a-plain/89338#89338

Comment: You can use a hair particle system

Comment: What kind of grass, realistic strands? low poly? Assuming the latter but try to be as specific as possible, as it is your question is still broad. Can you show an example of the type of grass you want to add?

Comment: please explain the hair particles system

Answer (score 1):

### Finished Result :

[image]

You will need to use a particle system :

- Be sure that the origin point of the objects (that will be placed) is down.
- Then select your objects and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
  <kbd>G</kbd>
- Select your plane where the grass objects will be placed, and in properties panel click on particle system and click plus
- Continue From here in images :

[image]

[image]

Be sure to put a check-mark beside advance :

[image]

[image]

Finished :
[image]

If you want decrease the number of objects just decrease the number.

Comment: thank you shams el-deen lets be friends here's my skype name Obafemi Oduola